# How to return the count of words from a list of words that appear in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, data-structures

I have a very large list of strings like this:

```
list_strings = ['storm', 'squall', 'overcloud',...,'cloud_up', 'cloud_over', 'plague', 'blight', 'fog_up', 'haze']
```

and a very large list of lists like this:

```
lis_of_lis = [['the storm was good blight'],['this is overcloud'],...,[there was a plague stormicide]]
```

How can I return a list of counts of all the words that appear in `list_strings` on each sub-list of `lis_of_lis`. For instance for the above example this will be the desired output: `[2,1,1]`

For example:

```
['storm', 'squall', 'overcloud',...,'cloud_up', 'cloud_over', 'plague', 'blight', 'fog_up', 'haze']

['the storm was good blight']
```

The count is 2, since `storm` and `blight` appear in the first sublist (lis_of_lis)

```
['storm', 'squall', 'overcloud',...,'cloud_up', 'cloud_over', 'plague', 'blight', 'fog_up', 'haze']

['this is overcloud stormicide']
```

The count is `1`, since `overcloud` appear in the first sublist (lis_of_lis)

**since stormicide doesnt appear in the first list**

```
['storm', 'squall', 'overcloud',...,'cloud_up', 'cloud_over', 'plague', 'blight', 'fog_up', 'haze']

[there was a plague]
```

The count is `1`, since `plague` appear in the first sublist (lis_of_lis)

Hence is the desired output `[2,1,1]`

**The problem with all the answers is that are counting all the substrings in a word instead of the full word**

Comment: How `[2,1,1]` will be the desired output?

Comment: storm and blight match the first item in `lis_of_lis`, overcloud is a single match in the second item, and plague is a single match in the third item : `[2,1,1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for sentence in lis_of_lis:
    result.append(0)
    for word in list_strings:
        if word in sentence[0]:
            result[-1]+=1
print(result)
```

which is the long version of

```
result = [sum(1 for word in list_strings if word in sentence[0])  for sentence in lis_of_lis]
```

This will return [2,2,1] for your example.

If you want only whole words, add spaces before and after the words / sentences:

```
result = []
for sentence in lis_of_lis:
    result.append(0)
    for word in list_strings:
        if ' '+word+' ' in ' '+sentence[0]+' ':
            result[-1]+=1
print(result)
```

or short version:

```
result = [sum(1 for word in list_strings if ' '+word+' ' in ' '+sentence[0]+' ')  for sentence in lis_of_lis]
```

This will return [2,1,1] for your example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, The problem with this aproach is that is counting the substrings. Any idea of how to just count the complete string?. Thanks in advance

Comment: For example, consider the followinf `lis_of_lis = [['the storm was good blight'],
              ['this is overcloud stormicide'],
              ['there was a plague']]`

Comment: This is counting the all the substrings, hence the output is worng.. Any idea of how to fix it?, thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for the help. And sorry If I was not clear, I edited the question and add more details. The problem with this is that is counting the substrings I would like to count the frecuency of all the words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` function within a list comprehension :

```
[sum(1 for i in list_strings if i in sub[0]) for sub in lis_of_lis]
```

Comment: @newWithPython sorry i have omitted the `for` try it now!

Comment: you should change your first sub to sub[0] since lis_of_lis is a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks for the help, The problem with this aproach is that is counting the substrings. Any idea of how to just count the complete string?. Thanks in advance

Comment: `[sum(1 for word in list_strings if word in sentence) for sublist in lis_of_lis for sentence in sublist]`

Comment: @ILostMySpoon thanks for reminding! i thought that elements of `sub` are splitted!

Answer (score 0):

This creates a dictionary with the words in list_string as keys, and the values starting at 0. It then iterates through the lis_of_lis, splits the phrase up into a list of words, iterates through that, and checks to see if they are in the dictionary. If they are, 1 is added to the corresponding value.

```
    word_count = dict()
    for word in list_string:
        word_count[word] = 0

    for phrase in lis_of_lis:
        words_in_phrase = phrase.split()
        for word in words_in_phrase:
            if word in word_count:
                word_count[word] += 1
```

This will create a dictionary with the words as keys, and the frequency as values. I'll leave it to you to get the correct output out of that data structure.